# How to Retrain a Production Model?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, unbalanced-classes

Suppose we have a marketing campaign which shows a banner to new customers saying the delivery fee is waived for the first order. The A/B testing shows that such banner is effective in increasing the conversion rate. Suppose we use the A/B testing data to build a classifier to identify new customers who are not serious and most likely will return the product of the first order. After deploying it into the production for 2 months, how to retrain the model? One solution comes to my mind is: select a small percentage of new customers(say 10%) to collect clean data again and then use it to build a new model. Obviously this is a costly approach. Is there any better solution for retraining the model?

Comment: So you want to retrain the model after seeing which of the people from the variant did not retain the product?  Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes you are right. I updated my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in why you think your proposed approach is costly?  Surely, the business would not be surprised that customers game the system.  To me, this sounds like the only way to solve the problem (barring cases where you might have prior information).

I don't think a classifier is the right approach here.  You would probably want risk estimates (i.e. probabilities) rather than 0/1 predictions.  That way you can at least check that your model is well calibrated.  Given that you have a well defined population from which you can sample from, I also think that you should avoid purposefully balancing the classes.  If the risk of returning the product is low, then your model should learn that rather than erroneously learn that the risk for the average customer is something like 50% just because you chose to balance classes.

Comment: It is costly because when we remove the model for 10% population, we will increase the loss of delivery fees without gaining additional revenue. Assume I use logistic regression model here and it will return probabilities.